# I get invalidRequest Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am integrating Onedrive SDK with the UWP part of my Xamarin App. Once I press the download button I get the Onedrive signin page but it throws the above error in this line:

```
     try
    {
        var appFolder = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(appFolder.Name);
    }
    catch (ServiceException e  )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message +"    " +  e.Error.Code);

    }
```

here is the full relevant code:

```
     public async Task Download(string filename)
{
    //AccountSelectionLoaded();
    await InitializeClient();
    try
    {
        var appFolder = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(appFolder.Name);
    }
    catch (ServiceException e  )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message +"    " +  e.Error.Code);

    }

    var file = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children[filename].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    //var fileStream = await fileBuilder.Content.Request().GetAsync();

    IStorageFile appFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.db3",
                        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    byte[] fileBytes;
   using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(file.AsInputStream()))
        {
            fileBytes = new byte[file.Length];
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)file.Length);
            reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
        }
   Debug.WriteLine(fileBytes.Length);
    Debug.WriteLine("Writing");
    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(appFile, fileBytes);
    Debug.WriteLine("End of writing");       
}

private async Task InitializeClient()
{
    if (OneDriveClient == null)
    {
        Task authTask;
        var msaAuthProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(oneDriveConsumerClientId,oneDriveConsumerReturnUrl,scopes);
        await msaAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
        OneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(oneDriveConsumerBaseUrl, msaAuthProvider);

        AuthenticationProvider = msaAuthProvider;


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working on this

Comment: Any updates? have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. Indeed, we can see a associated issue using OneDrive .NET SDK [2.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK/2.0.4) in a UWP app

I will report this issue through internal way.

As a workaround, please see this blog: [Windows 10 - Implementing a UWP App with the Official OneDrive SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx)

Laurent Bugnion described the detailed steps(and also a [demo](http://galasoft.ch/s/msdnonedrive2)) to enable OneDrive features in a UWP app.

```
private IOneDriveClient _client;
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  AuthenticateButton.Click += async (s, e) =>
  {
    var scopes = new[]
    {
      "onedrive.readwrite",
      "onedrive.appfolder",
      "wl.signin"
    };
    _client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetClientUsingOnlineIdAuthenticator(
      _scopes);
    var session = await client.AuthenticateAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Token: {session.AccessToken}");
  };
}
```

At that time, the project is using [**1.2.0 SDK**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK/1.2.0) which is **still working now**.